# Delete ALL albums?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

Due to a "bug" in one of our apps we have more than 1000(!) albums on a facebook page now. Question is how to delete all albums automatically? Is it possible to contact facebook here and ask for delete?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't provide a way to remove Albums via API so you'll probably will need to do that manually.